# Create a temp table in a view that holds number 1 to 1000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, temp-tables

I need to create a temporary table inside of a view that has one column with number one to 1000. Any ideas on how to do this?

I am using SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't create a temp table inside a view. Next... If you want the numbers 1-1000 inside a view consider using a tally table.

Comment: You could use a CTE to generate the numbers but a materialized tally table would be better.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have a permanent table of digits available, it has so many uses.

For a quick and dirty on-the-fly you can do

```
select distinct number from 
 master..spt_values
 where number between 1 and 1000
 order by number
```

You'd be better off just inserting into a permanent table though for reuse

```
select distinct Number 
into utils.Digits /* utils schema for example only */
 from 
 master..spt_values
 where number between 1 and 1000
```

And creating a unique clustered index on it.

Comment: `DISTINCT` does make this a little more expensive that it needs to be, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, it's only as I say a quick option, for a one -off. Using it to populate a permanent table as a one-off is best of course.

Answer (score 1):

The tally table solution is best (because of the index), but if you don't have one and need one, you can use a Common Table Expression in a pinch.

I normally use a ROW_NUMBER() and the sys.columns table. If I need LOTS of rows, I cross join back to sys.columns.

```
create view dbo.SomeView as 
with Tally as (
   select top(1000) row_number() over (order by A.object_id) as N
   from sys.columns A
   cross join sys.columns B -- If you need LOTS of rows, you add more cross joins
)
select *
  from something
  join Tally on Tally.N = something.N;
```